# How to notify the commenter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

If I write a comment on your status and then you comment back I don't get a notification to let me know you commented.

Currently only the owner of the status gets notifications. How can we make is where anyone who commented on a status should get notified too?

**models**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_notification
  has_many :notifications
  def create_notification
    author = valuation.user
    notifications.create(
      comment:      self,
      valuation:    valuation,
      user:         author,      
      read:         false
    )
  end
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :valuation
  belongs_to :user
end

class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comments
end
```

**controllers**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_commentable
    @commentable = find_commentable
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_commentable
    if params[:goal_id]
      Goal.find(params[:goal_id])
    elsif params[:habit_id]
      Habit.find(params[:habit_id])
    elsif params[:valuation_id]
      Valuation.find(params[:valuation_id])
    elsif params[:stat_id]
      Stat.find(params[:stat_id])
    end
  end
end

class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notifications = current_user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update_attribute(:read, true) 
    end
  end
end
```

**views**

```
#notifications/_notification.html.erb
commented on <%= link_to "your value", notification_valuation_path(notification, notification.valuation_id) %>

#comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your question is too generic. _"whenever a user comments on a status any comment that comes after on that status **should notify you** that an additional comment has been made"_. What do you need to know? Are you asking about how to know _when_ to notify, or are you asking about _how_ to notify the user? What exactly do you mean by _notifying_? Some value changed in a model, an email sent, a popup...

Comment: If I comment on your value. Then if you comment back on that value. I don't get a notification letting me know you commented. Only the person whose value it is gets the notification. Maybe there is a way in the `def create_notification` to make this work @brito

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Yes, because Notification is always created with `user:         author,`, and `author = valuation.user` (this is within `create_notification`). So you need to create that specific notification passing the `Comment`'s author instead of the `Valuation` author.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work @brito. For example, the comments are being made on valuation 1, which is owned by user 1. When user 2 comments on valuation 1, how is rails suppose to know that a comment from user 1 on valuation 1 is suppose to notify user 2? User 2 doesn't own valuation 1. Comments are made on valuations, even those that are meant as a reply to earlier comments. Maybe there is a way to say in code, "that valuation 1 belongs to user 2 too in terms of commenting/notifying"?

Comment: "how is rails suppose to know that a comment from user 1 on valuation 1 is suppose to notify user 2?" valuation 1 contains comments from user 1 and user 2, correct? Then it follows that valuation 1 can identify users 1 and 2. So you just have to iterate through each valuation's comments, store the unique users (because users may have commented more than once, and we only want 1 notification per user) and then notify them.

Comment: How can valuation 1 identify user 1 and 2, @brito? Can you please provide the answer below so I can give you credit if it works? I've been struggling with how to adapt your comment to an answer.

Comment: This post looks good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051523/comment-notification-to-users-in-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating one notification for the author, you have to retrieve the list of users who have commented on the valuation. I don't see a `belongs_to :user` in the Comment model, but I'll assume there is one, as you are able to do a `current_user.comments` in `CommentsController`.

Let's add a `has_many` relation in `Valuation` to retrieve all the commentators for a given valuation:

```
class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commentators, -> { distinct }, through: :comments, source: :user
end
```

If you are using a version of Rails < 4, you should replace `-> { distinct }` by `uniq: true`

Then, you can simply use this new relation to create notifications for all the commentators in the `Comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_notification
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :valuation
  has_many :notifications

  def create_notification
    to_notify = [valuation.user] + valuation.commentators
    to_notify = to_notify.uniq
    to_notify.delete(user)  # Do not send notification to current user
    to_notify.each do |notification_user|
      notifications.create(
        comment:      self,
        valuation:    valuation,
        user:         notification_user,      
        read:         false
      )
    end
  end
end
```